# How to add a row or column to a matrix in Python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how I can add row to a matrix in python numpy. For instance, in Matlab we can do `A=[1;zeros(10,1)]`, how can I do that in numpy?

Thanks.

Comment: `np.hstack` and `np.vstack` for example

Comment: That MATLAB syntax is equivalent to its `cat`, `horzcat` and `vertcat` functions.  In `numpy` `concatenate` is the basic function, `hstack` and `vstack` use it. Make sure you understand dimensions (especially the fact that `np.array` may have 0 or 1 dim, not just 2.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import numpy

...

# L is your 2-dimensional list

M = numpy.matrix(L)
# R is the list (i.e. a row) to add
M = numpy.vstack([M, R])
```